# Is it possible to enforce edges (constrained delaunay triangulation) in scipy.spatial's Delaunay?

Tags: python, scipy, triangulation, delaunay

I am experimenting with [scipy.spatial's implementation of Qhull's Delaunay triangulation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html).

Is it possible to generate the triangulation in a manner that preserves the edges defined by the input vertices? (EDIT: i.e. a constrained Delaunay triangulation.) As can be done with the [triangle package](http://dzhelil.info/triangle/) for Python.

For example, in the picture below there are several triangles (blue) that disregard the location of the edges (red) that are defined by the vertices. Is there a way to enforce these edges such that they are in all cases part of the triangulation result?

[image: Delaunay Triangulation]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [constrained Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation), and unfortunately the `scipy.spatial` implementation does not support it.

As you pointed out, [`triangle`](http://dzhelil.info/triangle/) does have that feature -- why not use it instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using triangle which works well for my purposes, though the underlying triangle package (which it wraps) does sometimes cause my python script to crash, so I was looking for a backup algorithm for 'just in case'.

Comment: @shongololo: Maybe it's worth reporting that as a bug in triangle if that is indeed the reason?

Comment: @cfh hi, yes, have done so but the problem can't be reproduced on their system (using linux whereas I am using mac)

Comment: @shongololo: I found [another library](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) which can do constrained Delaunay and has inofficial Python bindings. The code seams unmaintained, but maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Poly2Tri looks interesting and has a good reputation, but instructions on the Python bindings seem cryptic and the relatively old implementation makes me wonder if it is compatible with Python 3?

Comment: Has there been any work done to deal with adding constraints in a more supported library in the past 2+ years since this question was originally asked?