# Interpolate nodes from small graph onto large graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Ok here is the scenario. I have a *large* graph I'm calling G which contains position information for each node (x and y coordinates) as well as connecting edges. Graph G is ground truth. Now I have a smaller graph I am calling 'sub' which contains nodes which represent measurements that contain position error in both x and y. I need to project the nodes of sub onto G which preserves the obvious correct path along G. (See attached image and code).

I have code to project any individual node onto the graph but the placement of individual nodes typically causes the path from projected node a to projected node f to contain short in and out discontinuities along G (not in this particular example, my real problem is a much larger and more complicated graph which causes these discontinuities all the time). **My method of projection could be the problem in that I just check for the two closest nodes to the measured node and then project that node between those two. In this example, the top right red node would probably be projected onto the top-right black diagonal edge instead of on the vertical edge.**

I feel like there must be a way to do some sort of least squares fitting of path sub onto G, but I can't seem to find any details for something like this.

Does an algorithm exist to do this?

I'm sorry if I am not wording this well, I am very new to working with graphs and am not sure what the common nomenclature is.

[image: G and Sub]

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections as mc

def GetPlottingData(graph):
    lines = []
    for edge in graph.edges():

        x0 = graph.nodes[edge[0]]['x']
        y0 = graph.nodes[edge[0]]['y']
        x1 = graph.nodes[edge[1]]['x']
        y1 = graph.nodes[edge[1]]['y']

        lines.append([(x0, y0), (x1, y1)])

    node_x = []
    node_y = []
    for node in graph.nodes():
        x = graph.nodes[node]['x']
        y = graph.nodes[node]['y']
        node_x.append(x)
        node_y.append(y)

    return lines, node_x, node_y

G = nx.Graph()

nodes = [('A', {'x': -2, 'y': 0}),
         ('B', {'x': -1, 'y': 0}),
         ('C', {'x': 1, 'y': 0}),
         ('D', {'x': 2, 'y': 0}),
         ('E', {'x': 3, 'y': 0}),
         ('F', {'x': 1, 'y': 1}),
         ('G', {'x': 2, 'y': 1}),
         ('H', {'x': 3, 'y': 1}),
         ('I', {'x': 3, 'y': 2}),
         ('J', {'x': 4, 'y': 3}),
         ('K', {'x': 4, 'y': 1.5})]

edges = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('C', 'F'), ('D', 'G'),
         ('E', 'H'), ('F', 'G'), ('G', 'H'), ('G', 'I'), ('H', 'I'), ('H', 'K'),
         ('K', 'J'), ('I', 'J')]

G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

sub_nodes = [('a', {'x': -1.8, 'y': .2}),
             ('b', {'x': .7, 'y': .1}),
             ('c', {'x': 1.6, 'y': 1.1}),
             ('d', {'x': 2.9, 'y': 0.9}),
             ('e', {'x': 3.4, 'y': 1.3}),
             ('f', {'x': 4.1, 'y': 2.3})]

sub_edges = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('e', 'f')]

sub = nx.Graph()
sub.add_nodes_from(sub_nodes)
sub.add_edges_from(sub_edges)

main_lines, main_x, main_y = GetPlottingData(G)
sub_lines, sub_x, sub_y = GetPlottingData(sub)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches((8, 8))

main_lc = mc.LineCollection(main_lines, colors='black')
sub_lc = mc.LineCollection(sub_lines, colors='red')
ax.add_collection(main_lc)
ax.add_collection(sub_lc)

ax.scatter(main_x, main_y, color='black')
ax.scatter(sub_x, sub_y, color='red')
ax.autoscale()
ax.tick_params('both', labelsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel('X', size=13)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', size=13)
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Comment: This is similar to the computational geometry problem of aligning two point meshes with one another. IIRC there’s an algorithm called *iterated closest points* that can help here, but it might not be an exact match.

Comment: I am giving this a close vote as there are way to many questions I have after reading this.

Comment: @GuyCoder How is that a valid close reason? OP is doing his/her utmost to explain the problem and provides a MWE that illustrates the problem. What more do you want?

Comment: I think you should write the specification of each node as a list instead of a paragraph. I'm having a hard time discerning at a glance what each node/edge represents and is supposed to do. Expected input/output is also mangled with the problem statement, the problem lacks clarity because it demands too much effort of potential future readers to be easily read and understood.

Comment: I think I understood OP's problem just fine. OP, does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892564/find-nearest-edge-in-graph) illustrate your problem more succinctly? If so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034461/2912349) seems the most straightforward way to go about it.

Comment: There seems to be a constrained Delaunay triangulation in the `triangle` package as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386691/is-it-possible-to-enforce-edges-constrained-delaunay-triangulation-in-scipy-sp).

Comment: I vote to re-open as 1) OP clearly states the problem even though he or she lacks the domain terminology (while admitting as much), and 2) OP provides a MWE with executable code that reproduces the problem. [Another question with essentially the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892564/find-nearest-edge-in-graph) has 19 upvotes, which is far is above average for the `networkx` tag, and clearly demonstrates that the problem is non-trivial. None of the answers on that question provide any working solution in the form of code, so clearly there is room for a better answer.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen That is a very similar question to the one I posed above. While this might help me project individual nodes more accurately, I still wonder about a solution that can use information about node x-1 and x+1 to inform the placement of node x.

Comment: Could you provide an example or point out in your example graph, where predecessor or successor node position in the path would change the edge assignment?

Comment: There is an implementation in `osmnx` for `get_nearest_edges` [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/4c21f40c4839cd256656e4b695dd0f1fa4654cf9/osmnx/distance.py#L306). Although this implementation is probably not immediately useful for you as it requires the graph to be an osmnx graph (which is an extension of a networkx graph), it is instructive to see their approach: Basically, edges are converted into collections of points by densely subsampling positions along the edges, and then they use KD-Trees to efficiently find the nearest neighbours.

Comment: Using that approach, the search is going to be fast (N log(N), IIRC) but the memory requirements might be a limiting factor. Also, the solution would only be approximate, depending on the density of the subsampling. Could you provide an estimate of the number of nodes and edges in the graph and in the path?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen unfortunately I think my little toy example doesn't exactly highlight the problem of projected individual nodes incorrectly. I can update the question tomorrow with an example of when having information about the node before and after a node in a path would help project the middle node down correctly.

My graph has anywhere between ~35,000 nodes and ~40,000 edges to upwards of 320,000 nodes and 400,000 edges.

Comment: One of the biggest questions I have is that if I look at the image to me it seems that each path can be constructed by giving as sequence of angles from one vertex to the next. Then there would be a red path and a black path and then just finding patterns that are close would work. As I work with Prolog daily, this look like more of a pattern matching problem of done with syntax matching with some range for matching the next angle. But I don't know if that would be allowed by reading your description. You seem to allow for only one way to solve this and don't give enough info for other means.

Comment: Other information that is missing are enough true cases and false cases to check code created for this. As it stands I would not know if any code were correct or incorrect to solve this problem. Think many valid and invalid test cases and reasons why the invalid test cases are invalid.

Comment: What I am thinking might work is a modification of [DCGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar). I know DCGs are unknown by so many even those that write Prolog, but [here](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/dcg/) is a page that is at least somewhat closer than having no understanding of DCGs of how this might work. If you know Natural Language Processing with [ATNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_transition_network) that might also work.

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks for all the suggestions. I have updated the code to a give a specific example of a problem node that could benefit from adjacent information. Node 'd' in the red graph (fourth from right) using basically any interpolation method will be projected onto the vertical black edge instead of onto the horizontal edge directly above it. 

I don't care what form the solution takes. The short question is, "What is the best way to interpolate a point onto a graph? Can it be improved by knowing that point belongs to a path?"